# button available only when label is not nil

Tags: uitextfield

How can I force the user to insert data to the UITEXTFILED that otherwise the button will not work for him.

I thought about:

```
-(IBAction) signup:(id)sender{

if text.text==nil

///// return?? /////
?
```

tnx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do like this, first in my ViewDidLoad():

```
editButton.enabled=NO;
[_myTextFieldaddTarget:self 
                action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)    
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then i would add an event handler:

```
-(void) textFieldDidChange{
  if (_myTextField.length == 0){
    editbutton.enabled=NO;
  }else{
    editbutton.enabled=YES;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show an UIAlertView when the user push the button if the UITextField is empty :

```
if (_myTextField.lenght == 0)
// Display Alert
```